# How do I enable Modern Standby again (after disabling it via registry)

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, wake-up, standby

I have used PowerShell to deactivate Modern Standby on my Windows 10 machine following [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/wakeontouch) because my computer did not wake up on touch, and I wanted to test if disabling Modern Standby would solve my problem:

I used

PowerShell

```
reg add HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power /v PlatformAoAcOverride /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

This however did not help. In fact, my screen didn't go black (go so sleep any more at all), so I wanted to revert it.

However, I did not see any registry key HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power where I could reset it.

How do I reset it?

Thank you!

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HKLM` stands for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` in the registry editor, if that's why you couldn't find the path.

One way to remove the setting after you've added it is with powershell (running as admin):

```
Remove-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power' -Name PlatformAoAcOverride
```

---

Be careful with changes to the registry settings! Good practice is to export anything you're going to change as a backup beforehand.